# Excel VBA offset Copy Paste

Tags: excel, vba

Hope you're doing well.  I'm going to preface this by saying I'm not a programmer and I'm sure the code I have started is riddled with more errors then what I think.  Hopefully you can help :D.

I have an Excel sheet that gets generated from another program that comes out like this:

[excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4lUn.jpg)

However, the size of this sheet can change with every new generation of this sheet from the other program. (ex, A can have 7 next time, and D could have 9) And the sheet as it is cannot be used easily to do the math required as I only need specific groups of information at a given time, in this example groups B and D only.

What I'm hoping to create is something that will take the sheet as its generated, and turn it into something that looks like this:

[result sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jN9kP.jpg)

This is the code I've written so far, but since I don't really know what I'm doing I keep running into numerous problems.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Numbers()
Dim matchesFound As Integer
Dim row As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim copyRow As Integer
Dim copyLocationColumn As Integer

Dim arr(2) As String
arr(0) = "1"
arr(1) = "2"
arr(2) = "3"

Function arrayContainsValue(array, varValue) 
  found = false
  for each  = 0 to array 
    if array(i) = varValue then    
      found = true
      exit for       
  arrayContainsValue = found 
End Function

row = 1
c = 1
copyLocationColumn = 1
copyRow = 1

matchesFound = 0
Do While matchesFound < 3
  if arrayContainsValue(arr, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cell(column,row))

    matchesFound = matchesFound + 1
    Do While ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cell(column, row)
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("postHere").Cell(copyLocationColumn, copyRow) = _
                       ThisWorkbook.Sheets("postHere").Cell(c + 1, row)
      copyRow = copyRow+1
      row = row + 1
    Loop
  End If
 row = row + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many logic errors to numerate in a comment, Excel highlights them automatically I'll do a summary explaining them: 
1. Function can't be "in the middle" of the sub, finish the Sub (take the   Function from the sub and paste until it says end sub. 
2.array is a forbidden name, try with another variable name 
3.For each =0 ? to array? what do you try to mean like that? For Each has to be element in something For each element in Array for example For and To are for something defined in numbers  (for counter=1 to 15)

```
Function arrayContainsValue(***array***, varValue)  '2nd problem       
found = false
  for each  = 0 to array  '3rd problem
    if array(i) = varValue then    
      found = true
      exit for       
  arrayContainsValue = found 
End Function
```

....
4. you're missing a then at the end

```
if arrayContainsValue(arr, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cell(column,row))
```

I don't get the coding logic on how relates to the problem stated (?)